# Add new rows in the Spark DataFrame using scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like:

```
Name_Index  City_Index
  2.0         1.0
  0.0         2.0
  1.0         0.0
```

I have a new list of values.

```
list(1.0,1.0)
```

I want to add these values to a new row in dataframe in the case that all previous rows are dropped.

My code:

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .getOrCreate()


    var data = spark.read.option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv("src/main/resources/student.csv")

   val someDF = Seq(
         (1.0,1.0)
        ).toDF("Name_Index","City_Index")

   data=data.union(someDF).show()
```

It show output like:

```
Name_Index  City_Index
  2.0          1.0
  0.0          2.0
  1.0          0.0
  1.1          1.1
```

But output should be like this. So that all the previous rows are dropped and new values are added.

```
Name_Index   City_Index
  1.0          1.0
```

Comment: Do you want to drop all previous rows & only new rows are added to dataframe ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to delete all previous rows.

Comment: If you want to drop all the previous rows from the initial dataframe why not just call newRow.toDF

Comment: No. I just want to add these values to the old dataframe. But also want to delete all previous rows.

Comment: You can call second dataframe directly or if you still want to use both Try this - data.limit(0).union(someDF).show(false)

Comment: Okay. Let me try this limit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using limit & union functions. check below.

```
scala> val df = Seq((2.0,1.0),(0.0,2.0),(1.0,0.0)).toDF("name_index","city_index")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name_index: double, city_index: double]

scala> df.show(false)
+----------+----------+
|name_index|city_index|
+----------+----------+
|2.0       |1.0       |
|0.0       |2.0       |
|1.0       |0.0       |
+----------+----------+


scala> val ndf = Seq((1.0,1.0)).toDF("name_index","city_index")
ndf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name_index: double, city_index: double]

scala> ndf.show
+----------+----------+
|name_index|city_index|
+----------+----------+
|       1.0|       1.0|
+----------+----------+


scala> df.limit(0).union(ndf).show(false) // this is not good approach., you can directly call ndf.show
+----------+----------+
|name_index|city_index|
+----------+----------+
|1.0       |1.0       |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Yes, this is not a good approach. But I have a problem of this nature. That's why. Thank you so much by the way.

Answer (score 0):

change the last line to

```
data=data.except(data).union(someDF).show()
```

Comment: ```data = data.limit(0).union(someDF).show()```. This also has the same impact.

Comment: data.limit(0).union(someDF).show() is faster than except method..   :), check the performance if you have millions of records this will take time.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this approach

```
data = data.filter(_ => false).union(someDF)
```

output

```
+----------+----------+
|Name_Index|City_Index|
+----------+----------+
|1.0       |1.0       |
+----------+----------+
```

I hope it gives you some insights.

Regards.

Comment: This looks useful. But I have efficient solution ```data = data.limit(0).union(someDF).show()```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you only need the list of columns from source Dataframe.

If your sequence has the same order of the columns as the source Dataframe does, you can re-use schema without actually querying the source Dataframe. Performance wise, it will be faster.

```
    val srcDf = Seq((2.0,1.0),(0.0,2.0),(1.0,0.0)).toDF("name_index","city_index")

    val dstDf = Seq((1.0, 1.0)).toDF(srcDf.columns:_*)
```